# C, SDL: error: cannot convert 'SDL_Surface*' to 'SDL_Surface* (*)[15]

Tags: c, sdl

so I'm working on a code for filling a screen with a table of surfaces; here's the code:

main.c

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#include <cstdlib>
#else
#include <stdlib.h>
#endif

#include <SDL/SDL.h>
#include <SDL_image.h>
#include "maploader.h"

#define W 510
#define H 510
#define SIZE 34

void pause();

int main ( int argc, char** argv )
{
    SDL_Surface *screen = NULL;
    SDL_Surface *surfaces[15][15];



    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(W, H, 32, SDL_HWSURFACE | SDL_DOUBLEBUF);
    SDL_WM_SetCaption("demon game", NULL);
    SDL_FillRect(screen, NULL, SDL_MapRGB(screen->format, 255, 255, 255));
    mapload(screen, surfaces[15][15], NULL);

    SDL_Flip(screen);
    pause();
    SDL_QUIT;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}


void pause()
{
    int continuer = 1;
    SDL_Event event;

    while (continuer)
    {
        SDL_WaitEvent(&event);
        switch(event.type)
        {
            case SDL_QUIT:
            continuer = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

maploader.c

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#include <cstdlib>
#else
#include <stdlib.h>
#endif

#include <SDL/SDL.h>
#include <SDL_image.h>
#define W 510
#define H 510
#define SIZE 34



SDL_Surface *surfaces[15][15];


void mapload(SDL_Surface *screen, SDL_Surface *surfaces[][15], int lvl)
{
    FILE *level = NULL;
    char elements[125];
    int i, j, k = 0;
    SDL_Rect elementposition = {0,0};


    level = fopen("level.txt", "r");
    if (level == NULL)
    {
        exit(0);
    }
    fgets(elements, 125, level);
    SDL_FillRect(screen, NULL, SDL_MapRGB(screen->format, 255, 255, 255));
    for (i=0; i<15; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<15; j++)
        {
            if (elements[k] == "0")
            {
                surfaces[i][j] = IMG_Load("mur.jpg");
            }
            else if (elements[k] == "1")
            {
                surfaces[i][j] = IMG_Load("caisse.jpg");
            }
            else if (elements[k] == "2")
            {
                surfaces[i][j] = IMG_Load("objectif.png");
            }
            else
            {
                surfaces[i][j] = NULL;
            }
            k++;

        }

    }

    for (i=0; i<15; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<15; j++)
        {
            SDL_BlitSurface(surfaces[i][j], NULL, screen, &elementposition);
            elementposition.x += SIZE;
        }
        elementposition.y += SIZE;
    }




}
```

the only error I get from compiling is the following: **"cannot convert 'SDL_Surface*' to 'SDL_Surface* (*)[15]' for argument '2' to 'void mapload(SDL_Surface*, SDL_Surface* (*)[15], int)'|"**

apparently, the error is initialized from the second argument of the mapload function, but I don't have a clear idea about what exactly is wrong. any ideas, please?

Comment: The expression `surfaces[15][15]` get the *sixteenth* element of the *sixteenth* array from `surfaces`. I suggest you get [a good beginners book or two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and re-read the chapters on pointers and arrays.

Comment: unrelated, but don't even try to write **source** files that are valid C **and** valid C++ ... nothing to gain here, but a lot to loose. `#ifdef __cplusplus` is for header files only, to describe your interface in a way usable from both languages.

Comment: `surfaces[15][15]` is 1.) out of bounds 2.) of scalar type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This,

```
mapload(screen, surfaces[15][15], NULL);
```

should be

```
mapload(screen, surfaces, NULL);
```

But now you should ask yourself, if you didn't know that then probably,

- The signature of `void mapload(SDL_Surface *screen, SDL_Surface *surfaces[][15], int lvl)` is altogether wrong.
- You need to study what are arrays in [c](/questions/tagged/c) and their relation to pointers.

Note that `surfaces[15][15]` means the *16th* element of the *16th* array of pointers, none of which exists because you only allocated 15 of each. So you need to understand arrays in [c](/questions/tagged/c), how they are allocated and how you can have a dynamic array.

Also, the fact that you tell a [c](/questions/tagged/c) compiler that a function is expecting an array is not very relevant inside such function, so the syntax `SDL_Surface *surfaces[][15]` seems strange to a c programmer.

And finally, since `surfaces` is a global variable you don't need to pass it as a parameter, but then you should ask yourself, *should it be a global variable*?